# EF 4.1 / Repository / UnitOfWork / MySQL : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4.1, repository, unit-of-work

I read all the similar titles questions, but i didn't find the answer to my problem, so I open a new question:

I have two mysql tables:

- tb1 (int_id, code, description, ..., my_id);
- tb2 (int_id, code, description, ..., tb1_id);

I create a generic repository to manage DbContext and GetAll, GetById, GetByLambda, Insert, Update and Delete methode.

```cs
namespace Model.DataAccessLayer
{
  public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityObject, IEntity
  {
    protected DbContext dbContext = null;

    public virtual DbContext DbContext
    {
      get { return dbContext; }
      set { dbContext = value; }
    }

    public ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
      get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      ObjectContext.Dispose();
      System.GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
      return ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByLambda(Func<T, bool> p)
    {
      return GetAll().Where(p);
    }


    public virtual void Save()
    {
      DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    ...

  }
}
```

and the inherited class which I used:

```cs
namespace Model.DataAccessLayer
{
  public class RepositoryP<T> : Repository<T> where T : EntityObject, IEntity
  {
    public myEntities MyContext
    {
      get { return (myEntities)ObjectContext; }
      //set { ObjectContext = value; }
    }

    public override DbContext DbContext
    {
      get
      {
        if (dbContext == null)
        {
          dbContext = new DbContext("myEntities");
        }
        return dbContext;
      }
      set
      {
        base.DbContext = value;
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

It works great when using only one table.
When I try to use my two tables and the foreign key relation between them, it doesn't work. 
For example I try to get all records from table tb2 where tb1.my_id=5 with the following join tb1.int_id = tb2.tb1_id.

```cs
List<tb2> lj = new Tb2DAO().GetByLambda(l => l.tb1.my_id == 5).ToList();
```

(Tb2DAO inherited from my generic repository class.)

I have the following MySQL error:

**"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."**

I think this comes from my DbContext which is not common to my two tables entities.
So I tried to implement the UnitOfWork Pattern to solve this problem, like this:

```cs
namespace Model.DataAccessLayer
{
  public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
  {
    private DbContext dbContextUnit = null; //= new DbContext();
    private Tb1DAO tb1DAO;
    private Tb2DAO tb2DAO;

    public Tb1DAO tb1
    {
      get
      {

        if (this.tb1DAO == null)
        {
          if (dbContextUnit != null)
          {
            this.tb1DAO = new Tb1DAO { DbContext = dbContextUnit };
          }
          else
          {
            this.tb1DAO = new Tb1DAO();
            dbContextUnit = this.tb1DAO.DbContext;
          }

        }
        return tb1DAO;
      }
    }

    public Tb2DAO tb2
    {
      get
      {

        if (this.tb2DAO == null)
        {
          if (dbContextUnit != null)
          {
            this.tb2DAO = new Tb2DAO { DbContext = dbContextUnit };
          }
          else
          {
            this.tb2DAO = new Tb2DAO();
            dbContextUnit = this.tb2DAO.DbContext;
          }
        }
        return tb2DAO;
      }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
      dbContextUnit.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (!this.disposed)
      {
        if (disposing)
        {
          dbContextUnit.Dispose();
        }
      }
      this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

  }
}
```

And now in my code I tried to use the Unit of Work like this :

```cs
UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
List<tb2> tb2List = unitOfWork.tb2.GetByLambda(l => l.index_job.job_id == job_id).ToList();
```

But I have always the same error message :

**"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."**

is there something I am doing wrong ? Please can you help me ? This notion of repository and unit Of work are new for me 
and I am confused else I read lot of think about it may be not the right one...

I also to try to add MultipleActiveResultSets=true to my connection but it is not recognized.

many thank to all & regards,
wst

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetByLambda()` method is calling `GetAll()` which creates a new context using `ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>()`.  So you now have more than one context open.  I would advise using the standard EF associations and the repository pattern, then you can avoid this entire mess.  Here is a link that may help you get started - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this method

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
}
```

It's create **new** object set about which EF context doesn't know.

You can try to pass `Func<ObjectContext, ObjectResult<T>>` from derived class to base. (It should return ObjectResult which are got from EF context. F.e. `context => context.Entities`).